# Checking if products listed in excel have their images placed in outside directory is not working. VBA, EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print 1 in B column for id which has relevant photo in directory ps_ean and 0 for id which doesnt have relevant photo. My code seems legit and is compiling, but is giving me all 0 or if I put at first row id which has a photo is giving it 1 and all other rows 0. Seems to me like some small mistake which I cannot find, however I am completely new to vba so maybe is some lack of basic knowledge, thanks for help.

Code is loop in loop which is taking id by id and comparing each of them to each file, where correct match should break second loop and go to next id of first loop. I know that it is not probably the most efficent way but seemed to me the fastest to write and on other hand there is no so much data (around 300 photos, 600 id)

Code in VBA:

```
Sub Check_if_photo_exist()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim value_s As String
MyFolder = "C:\Users\sabo\Desktop\ps_ean"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")
myrange = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("A1:A407")
For r = 1 To 407
    cel = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(r, 1)
    check = 0
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        value_s = CStr(Left(MyFile, Len(MyFile) - 4))
        If StrComp(CStr(cel), value_s, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(r, 2).Value = 1
            check = 1
        End If
        If check = 1 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    If check <> 1 Then
        Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(r, 2).Value = 0
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Excel example:

| id | exist |
| --- | --- |
| 34465 |  |
| 54667 |  |
| 35565 |  |
| 76678 |  |
| 10023 |  |

Photos name example:

34465.jpg
10023.jpg
76678.jpg

So what I want would be this:

| id | exist |
| --- | --- |
| 34465 | 1 |
| 54667 | 0 |
| 35565 | 0 |
| 76678 | 1 |
| 10023 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Okey I found my mistake finally.

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")
```

should be directly before Do while loop inside for loop